# Angular - Get object from foreign key

Tags: angular, loops, foreign-keys, observable

I started to work with Angular recently and i am currently facing an issue which is something very common.

So let's say i have a class Employee like :

```
class Employee{
    name : string;
}
```

then i have another class Project with two employees as foreign key :

```
class Project{
    subject : string;
    employee1_id : number;
    employee2_id : number;
}
```

Now, I would like to display all the projects BUT i want to display the name of the employees.

So it means that i have to :

1. Get all the project
2. For each project
   a. Get the first Employee by id
   b. Get the second Employee by id

Then i will have to add evreything in a list to display it.

My issue is that i didn't find any solution to get the list of projects and then for each of them be able to get the two employee depending of their id for the current project.

In fact, after the call of all projects, i don't know how i can use again two Oservable for each employee, and doing this in a loop. I am realy stuck and i don't understand why it seems to be so hard as it is for me something really common.

Again, i am new with Angular so the issue is problably me, that's why i need your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have a backend for this?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems your backend does not provide you with a matching resource, so I assumed that you can get all Projects and all Employees as a list. 
I've made a working example at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tl5iym), so you can follow up there.

### Mapping Employees with Projects

You can map the name of an Employee by using the `map()` function on an array. This lets you define a new object out of each existing object in the array. By doing this you can enhance it with the information you need (the name), while keeping the context of the object.

```
this.projectsWithEmployeeName = this.backendService.getAllProjects().map(project => {
      return {
        subject: project.subject,
        employee1_id: project.employee1_id,
        employee1_name: this.backendService.getEmployeeById(project.employee1_id).name,
        employee2_id: project.employee2_id,
        employee2_name: this.backendService.getEmployeeById(project.employee2_id).name
      }
    })
```

This assumes you have the following Backend Service:

#### Backend

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Project, Employee } from './models';

@Injectable()
export class BackendService {

  constructor() { }

  public getAllProjects(): Project[] {
    return [
      { subject: 'Project Almanac', employee1_id: 1, employee2_id: 2 },
      { subject: 'Project Kitten', employee1_id: 2, employee2_id: 3 },
      { subject: 'Project Unicorn', employee1_id: 3, employee2_id: 1 },
    ]
  }


  public getAllEmployees(): Employee[] {
    return [
      { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Sarah' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Mary' }
    ]
  }

  public getEmployeeById(id: number): Employee {
    return this.getAllEmployees().find(employee => {
      return employee.id === id;
    })
  }
}
```

This allows you to get a List of Employees and Projects, wich are defined as following:

```
export interface Project {
  subject: string;
  employee1_id: number;
  employee2_id: number;
}

export interface Employee {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

You can also switch out the functionality of the `getEmployeeById()` Function in order to call your backend, but than you should consider [some type of caching](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/caching-with-rxjs-observables-in-angular-2.0).